# Custom armor stand name with multiple lines

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make an armor stand with a custom name. Unfortunately I wasn't able to skip lines even when using the new line operator for Java or JSON or whatever. Here is the command:

```
/summon armor_stand ~ ~2 ~ {Invisible:1b,Invulnerable:1b,NoGravity:1b,Marker:1b,CustomName:"{\"text\":\"something \\n something\",\"color\":\"green\"}",CustomNameVisible:1b}
```

Answer (score 2):

Line feed characters do not work in entity names. The only way is to summon a second armour stand underneath it with a second custom name. I recommend either setting `NoAI:1b` or continuous teleports to make sure that the second armour stand does not move.

Comment: just a slight comment, if you want to make an armor stand not move, give it the Marker:1b tag. This essentially makes it non-interactable